# How to conditionally bind a instance depending on the injected type using unity?

Tags: unity-container, ioc-container, ninject

I'm used to Ninject, and for a specific project I'm asked to learn Unity.

There is one thing i can't find information on how to do.

In Ninject I can state:

```
Bind<IWarrior>().To<Samurai>().Named("Samurai");
Bind<IWarrior>().To<Ninja>().Named("Ninja");
Bind<IWeapon>().To<Katana>().WhenInjectedInto(typeof(Samurai));
Bind<IWeapon>().To<Shuriken>().WhenInjectedInto(typeof(Ninja));
```

And then when one asks for the warrior named samurai, the samurai comes with kanana and the ninja comes with shurikens. As it should.

I don't want to reference the container in the warriors to get the appropriate weapon, and don't want to contaminate the model with attributes (is in another assembly that doesn't have reference to ninject or unity)

PD: I'm looking for a code way, not via xml config.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work with Unity:

```
Container
 .Register<IWeapon, Katana>("Katana")
 .Register<IWeapon, Shuriken>("Shuriken")
 .Register<IWarrior, Samurai>("Samurai", new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IWeapon>("Katana"))
 .Register<IWarrior, Ninja>("Ninja", new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IWeapon>("Shuriken")));
```

---

**Test**:

```
var samurai = Container.Resolve<IWarrior>("Samurai");
Assert.IsTrue(samurai is Samurai);
Assert.IsTrue(samurai.Weapon is Katana);

var ninja = Container.Resolve<IWarrior>("Ninja");
Assert.IsTrue(ninja is Ninja);
Assert.IsTrue(ninja.Weapon is Shuriken);
```

Comment: Sure that does a **WhenInjectedInto** ?

Comment: I added a test section to show what that code registers in the container. It should be what the OP is looking for.

Comment: InjectionConstructor does not have any type parameters, or am I missing an import somewhere?

Comment: Am I right in thinking there is no way to make this work without specifying every constructor parameter individually? :(