# Conditionally inject dependency using Unity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I am using Unity (DI) to inject my registration service into my controller.

**Controller**

```
public class RenewalController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRegistrationService _registrationService;
    private readonly IRenewalTypedFactory _renewalFactory;

    public RenewalController(IRegistrationService registrationService, IRenewalTypedFactory renewalFactory)
    {
        _renewalFactory = renewalFactory;
        _registrationService = registrationService;
    }

    // GET: Renewal
    public ActionResult Renew()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

**Unity Config**

```
container.RegisterType<IRegistrationService, RegistrationService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
```

There was already a Registration service however I have now had to create a Renewal service class which is overriding a method.

```
public class RenewalService : RegistrationService, IRegistrationService
{
   ...
}
```

**How do I tell my Unity config to inject in my Renewal Service for my `IRegistrationService`, only when my controller is asking for it?**

I know in Ninject you would do something like:

```
.WhenInjectedInTo(typeof(RenewalController));
```

And I have read this question, but cannot get my head around it, or apply it to my example:

[How to conditionally bind a instance depending on the injected type using unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004306/how-to-conditionaly-bind-a-instance-depending-on-the-injected-type-using-unity)

Comment: Why can't you just create another interface, `IRenewalService`, and use it?

Comment: Unity has an option to specify a name for registration like `container.Register<IFoo, Bar>("name1")`. Then you can get specific registration by calling `container.Resolve<IFoo>("name1")`. To apply this to MVC you will need to customize MVC's workflow. Or google it, probably someone already did this.

Comment: @ieaglle no need to customize MVC, there's a `[Dependency("<name>")]` attribute

Comment: You could use Dynamic Composition Resolution as seen here: http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/how-not-to-do-dependency-injection-the-static-or-singleton-container

Comment: @SergRogovtsev, thanks I didn't know that!

Comment: How are you using the Unity container? via a custom IControllerFactory? or a custom IDependencyResolver? or by using the UnityDependencyResolver class from Unity.Mvc4 nuget package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell the container what dependency it should inject into `RenewalController`

```
container.RegisterType<RenewalController>(new InjectionConstructor(
             new ResolvedParameter<RenewalService>(), 
             new ResolvedParameter<IRenewalTypedFactory>()));
```